# TheeJs loaded and compressed gltf error'Draco Decoder Module is not defined at eval'

Tags: three.js

I used Google's DRACO Loader to load the compressed gltf model, but reported an error in the console:'Draco Decoder Module is not defined at eval'.

I don't know how to modify it.

Here's part of the code

```
const GLTFLoader1 = new GLTFLoader();
  GLTFLoader1.setPath(path);
  THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('../../../../../node_modules/three/examples/js/libs/draco/');
  THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: 'js' });
  GLTFLoader1.setDRACOLoader(new THREE.DRACOLoader());
  GLTFLoader1.load('0326-processed.gltf', (v) => {
    console.log(v)
    // const dataArr = v.scene;
    // dataArr.children.forEach((d) => {
    //   scene.add(d);
    // });
  });
```

What shall I do?

Comment: Did you include DRACOLoader.js on your page? It's not included by default

Comment: yes,I've added loader to my page

Comment: I think the problem is ‘THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('../../../../../node_modules/three/examples/js/libs/draco/');’ But I don't know how to solve it.